# Is the parachute using stall drag to reduce the descent speed?

Tags: drag, aerodynamics, lift

Is the parachute using stall drag to reduce the descent speed?  Because the parachute falls vertically, if we think of the parachute as a wing, then this is a very large angle of attack.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes, if it is the normal round parachute. Para-gliders obviously work on the wing-lift principle.

Comment: What are Para-gliders?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragliding